# Disable directory listing, python http Server

Tags: python, http.server

I have written a webUi in python (which is safely isolated from the internet, but I do not want the directory to be searchable).

How can I disable the directory listing if I use e.g. this link?

https://localhost:8080///

Comment: If you checked the documentation for [`http.server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler) you may come across the note about the `list_directory` method - just override that.